# Sending a message from child to parent process when spawned via npm script

Tags: node.js, npm

When I spawn a child process via an npm script, I lose the ipc channel.

I have a child script like this

```
if (process.send) { process.send('child') }
```

And if spawn it from another script like so, the parent process will successfully receive and print message

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn
spawn('node', ['child.js'], {stdio: ['inherit', 'inherit', 'inherit', 'ipc'})

spawn.on('message', function (msg) { console.log(msg) })
```

But if I define `node child.js` as an npm script in my package.json such as

```
"scripts": {
    "child": "node child.js"
}
```

and do this instead `spawn('npm', ['run', 'child'], {stdio: ['inherit', 'inherit', 'inherit', 'ipc'})`

`process.send` in my child script is undefined. I imagine this is because npm is now spawning the process and that process doesn't inherit my `stdio` settings. Perhaps there's a way around this. The npm scripts documentation doesn't mention the topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's an expected behaviour. `npm` is just a proxy that would spawn `node` and finish execution, so you've never had channels to the running node application in the first place. There's no way around this.